# Declaring a new object via variable name

Tags: c#, class, variables, void, protected

I'm fairly new to C# (and programming in general) so stick with me if I make any huge errors or talk complete bull. 
So what I'm trying to do is have a private void that resizes the background image of a button. I send the name of the button to the private void via a string. Anyway, the code looks something like this:

```
ButtonResize("Zwaard");


protected void ButtonResize(string Button)
    {
        string ButNaam = "btn" + Button;
        Button Butnaam = new Button();
        Butnaam.Text = ButNaam;

        if (Butnaam.BackgroundImage == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var bm = new Bitmap(Butnaam.BackgroundImage, new Size(Butnaam.Width, Butnaam.Height));
            Butnaam.BackgroundImage = bm;
        }
     }
```

But it doesn't work like that. I can't seem to find a way to declare a new object named the value I have in a string. What I want my code to do is instead of making a button called "Butnaam", I want it to create a button called btnZwaard (the value of the string Butnaam).

How do I tell C# I want the value of the variable to be the name of a new button, not literally what I type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are probably ways to do something like that using reflection, but don't.  It's a bad idea. Create a single Dictionary object that maps names to objects, and use your dynamically created name as the dictionary key, rather than as a variable name.

Comment: Do you really want to create a new button each time?  If it worked, that's what your current code would do.

Comment: Well, actually no, but I can't seem to acces the properties of my desired button from the protected void, so I figured I just had to create an object named the same, acces it's properties and it would change for my original button as well.. if you get my drift.

I'm probably just way overthinking this though. What I want that piece of code to do is actually change the size of my backgroundimage of a desired button (of which I send the name)

Comment: @Glenn: `"so I figured I just had to create an object named the same, acces it's properties and it would change for my original button as well"` - .... not quite.  If you need to modify an existing object, then you need a reference to that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?  By passing the `Button` to the method you can then act on the object.  If this is what you are looking for then you should read [Passing Reference-Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx)

```
protected void ButtonResize(Button button)
    {
        if (button != null && button.BackgroundImage != null)
        {
            button.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(button.BackgroundImage, new Size(newWidth, newHeight));
        }
     }
```

Comment: Yes, this is it exactly! Just by seeing the answer it actually looks quite logical you'd have to do it like that... Stupid me :p Thank you :)

Comment: @Glenn Don't forget to mark me as the answer.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

A string is a piece of text. You subsequently refer to it as a `class`, which is wrong. Assuming it were right you create a new button rather than "resize its image".

What you want to do to get you started is create a new function in the same class as the dialog that has the button. That function can resize the image of the control.

**Edit**: this doesn't seem like a good starting point for learning a language, btw. Please find a good online tutorial for starting in C# (e.g. a hello world application).

Comment: I appreciate your time for answering. And you're right, it probably isn't a good starting point. Right now I'm just casually trying to piece together some sort of game. To get the ropes of C# but also have some fun.

The problem is that when I have something in my mind, I must make it happen, which sometimes leads me to a lot of harder material. I do learn fast though and I can understand stuff out of context when the context is added later :)

Comment: Good for you; you've gotta keep in interesting. It *appears* you don't have a grasp of the basics of classes and objects (object oriented programming), which the deep end 'aint gonna help you with. Look them up!

Comment: You're completely right. I didn't even know about classes at first. I was trying to program something very complicated when a friend of mine recommended I used classes instead. It made the project 4 times easier. 

So yeah, I should probably just go do some general reading to grasp the basics. Whenever I read something though, after a few lines I get the feeling "Yes, I understand this, I want to implement this". Close the guide or whatever and just start bungling around in VS. A very bad habit indeed.

Comment: It probably means you'll be a good software engineer, because you have that trait of just wanting to make things work and get stuff done. It takes me a lot of self-control to learn something new for exactly the same reason. Best of luck!!